# Sweet alert JS library - modify animation speed

Tags: javascript, performance, popupwindow, sweetalert

I would like to make the animation speed for Sweet Alert popup a little slower.
I tried to search in everywhere,documents,web,forums but with not so much success.
How can I decrease the animation speed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original sweet alert plugin is unsupported, I suggest you using [SweetAlert2](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2) plugin.

Migration is simple, here's the migration guide: [Migration from SweetAlert to SweetAlert2](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/wiki/Migration-from-SweetAlert-to-SweetAlert2)

In SweetAlert2 you can change the animation speed by overriding the show and hide classes:

```js
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Custom animation speed',
  showClass: {
    popup: 'slow-animation-show'
  },
  hideClass: {
    popup: 'slow-animation-hide'
  }
})
```

```css
.slow-animation-show {
  animation: swal2-show 3s; 
}

.slow-animation-hide {
  animation: swal2-hide 3s; 
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to search in your quelltext for code like this:

```
 animation: animateSuccessTip 0.75s;
```

I think you should try to change the values that have this "s"(seconds i guess) Suffix. Just change it to a high value and check if its the right one.